# Unable to run Wildfly 8.1.0 as Service on Windows Server 2012 - Extended Attributes are Inconsistent?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-service, wildfly8

I'm attempting to get Wildfly 8.1.0.Final to run as a service on Windows Server 2012. I cd'd into `%Wildfly_Home%\bin\service` and ran `service install` in cmd.

It output this:

```
Using the X86-64bit version of prunsrv
Success
```

A service named Wildfly was added to my Windows Services. But when I attempt to start it, it tells me this:

> Windows could not start the Wildfly on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 255.

In the Windows Event Viewer, it says this:

> The Wildfly service terminated with the following service-specific error:
>
> The extended attributes are inconsistent.

What is this talking about? I'm guessing I might need to do something in the system registry since Google turned up a few results of people saying my registry was corrupted. I don't want to just run some automated tool though - that risks just messing up my registry in other ways. I want someone to actually tell me what's wrong so I can actually fix it. I looked over the Wildfly registry entries and it all looked fine to my relatively inexperienced eyes.

Comment: Try with remove the service and install again with latest version of `service.bat` https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/master/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/docs/contrib/scripts/service/service.bat

Comment: @FedericoSierra - I'm currently investigating just using `prunsrv` directly and not going through the `service.bat` file.

Answer (score 1):

Copy C:\Windows\system32\findstr.exe to Java\jdk\bin OR Java\jre\bin as applicable.

This resolved my problem.

Comment: it worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried a lot of suggestions, such as:
- moving the Wildfly files to a location which path didn't contain whitespaces
- removing the quotemarks in the Display name field of service.bat (but apparently using the new version of service.bat cited above is equivalent)
- moving findstre.exe to Java\jdk\bin as said above

And the last change I performed before it finally worked was to add to the PATH environment variable the ..\Java\jdk directory as JAVA_HOME, NOT the ..\Java\jdk**\bin** directory as I read somewhere.

Uninstall and reinstalled service between each modification.